# Web scraping from a google search page using html tag

Tags: web-scraping, uipath

I'm trying to do a google search and get the first 5 result (title/URL) into a excel document.

I tried using 'Data Scraping' but depending on the search term, google will display a different page. Sometimes its will have video, images or related search term. So most of the time, I was not able to actually get all the result from the page as uiPath would not recognize them, probably because of the different div. So my thought was to get them by html tag, as every title use H3 but I can't find a way to do that.

Also tried with find children > get attributes but no success, I feel that might be the best ways tho, I'm just not enough experimented with it to make it work. Tried for hours.

Anyone had a similar problem and found a solution?

Comment: @JimGrigoryan I use uiPath to get used to the program, its not for a project that I actually need or will be used anywhere. So i'm really trying to find a solution with uiPath. Thanks for the alternative solution tho. :)

Answer (score 0):

When I did this before I had to do multiple scrapes to get the data.  The first scrape will get the initial page results and then you can do a second to get data on page 2 forward.   I have had instances where i had to do multiple scrapes on the first page to get all the information but after page 1 the data is consistent and easy to scrape.  Hope this helps.